# Setting the correct regex

Tags: javascript, regex

I have a problem with my regex, I just need to quote only the price of the products from this string, I used this Regex but it did not help me, can anyone fix it? Thank you

A word from which I only need 69
LEUWIN 4XL CHF 69.–

my try:

```
var re = /[0-9]{2}/;
```

I take it from this field (picture below)

[image]

It works for me in all cases except in this one

[image]

so far I have used this regex in function, but now I only read the first number so I have to replace, otherwise the price and the number are always the same

```
function calculateSumWithInput(e) {
  var re = /\d+/;
  var value = re.exec(e.target.value);
  if (value && !isNaN(value) && Number(value) === parseInt(value, 10)) {
    sum = parseInt(value, 10);
    finalInput.value =  "CHF " + sum + ".–";
  }
}
```

thank you all for help

Comment: Try `/\b[A-Z]{3}\d+\b/`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Unfortunately no

Comment: Is the product *always* at the end of the string? Can you post some more sample inputs, and expected output?  Also, do you want to keep the `.-`?

Comment: Then `/\b[A-Z]{3}\s?\d+\b/`? `/\b[A-Z]{3}\s?\d{2}\b/`?

Comment: From your example, I would say /.*(CHF \d+).*/

Comment: I have corrected my question, please take a look

Comment: In my first example, my regex is working for me, but in the second it is not clear, only 4, instead of 69

Comment: Will there be decimal parts in your prices? Like CHF 5.5?

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote a mistake, I only need 69 to quote, the last digit

Comment: Then, try: `\d+(?=\.\–)`

Comment: @rv7 Perfect, that is it, thank you very much for help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract digits [followed by](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html) `.–`. Try:

```
\d+(?=\.\–)
```

Answer (score 0):

Judging from your example, I would suggest that you use this regex:

```
 /.*(CHF \d+).*/
```

You should test it, then access the second element of the array that will be the output of match. Assuming that the input is the variable text and the output must be saved to the variable price:

```
if(/.*(CHF \d+).*/.test(text)) price = text.match(/.*(CHF \d+).*/)[1];
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to match the currency code, which always starts with three uppercase characters (`[A-Z]{3}`).

Followed by at least a number describing the integer part (`\d+`).

Followed by a period (`\.`, we must escape the period, as it is a special character in regex).

Ending with the decimal part (`\d+`) *or* a dash `-`.

This leaves us with:

```
/[A-Z]{3} \d+\.(\d+|-)/
```

In any case, when making a regex it's important to give some detail about the exact pattern you want to match.

Comment: I'm sorry, I wrote a mistake, I only need 69 to quote, the last digit